# Prawn set cell color under a condition while making a table

Tags: ruby, prawn

I'm trying to generate a table while changing the background color of a cell under a condition. I've resorted coming to here for help. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
        idx = 0 

        pdf.table(myTable) do
            style(row(0), :background_color => 'ff00ff')
            style(column(0))
            while idx <= totalRows
                if cells[idx,3] == "No go"
                    style(cells[idx,3], :background_color => 'fF0000')
                else 
                    style(cells[idx,3], :background_color => '00FF22')
                end 
            idx += 1 
            end 
          
        end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does it work? If not I recommend you describe what goes wrong? What happens to the cell? What error messages?

Comment: undefined method `style' for nil:NilClass is the error I get. It seems that trying to access a cell individually in the do loop doesn't work when trying to iterate through them.

Comment: Thanks. Please paste the _exact_ error message into your question. Ruby normally gives a line number in every error message: as there are a 4 lines with 'style', readers of the question can't tell which one it is without running the code themselves.

Comment: What do you want this line to do? `style(column(0))`

Answer (score 0):

#### Call `#style` correctly

In version 0.2.2 of prawn-table, the `#style` method is defined on a cell, or an array of cells, so you need to get that first. The argument is merely a hash of the keys and values for the styles you want. For example, `row(0)` is an array of cells, so you can style it with a magenta background like this:

```rb
  pdf.table(myTable) do        
    row(0).style(:background_color => 'ff00ff')
  end
```

[image: first row of example table has magenta background]

You can refer to the full source code of `#style` at

- https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table/blob/0.2.2/lib/prawn/table/cells.rb#L139  and
- https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table/blob/0.2.2/lib/prawn/table/cell.rb#L227

#### `column(0)`

I am not sure what you want the line `style(column(0))` to do, so I can't advise on that.

#### Condition when "No go"

It looks like you want the while loop to apply a condition to the fourth column, so that cells whose content is 'No go' are red, while the rest are green.

For this, you can use the iterator built-in to the `#style` method, instead of your while loop. It could look like this:

```
    column(3).style do |cell|
       if cell.content == "No go"
         cell.style(:background_color => 'ff0000')
       else
         cell.style(:background_color => '00ff22')
       end
    end
```

[image: column(3) is styled based on a condition]

If you wanted something slightly different you should know enough now to vary the code.